# Sed (or other command) replace character range with hex codes

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

Let's say we have a file with non-printable characters.
I would like to visualize those using their hex codes. Arte there a single liners that can achieve it, without writing a full-blown program.

say in this example:

```
printf '\x1F-1f\x09-09\x0A\-oa\x0D-0d\x02' |sed -r 's/[^[:print:][:space:]]/CODE/g'
```

I replace all non-printable characters with "CODE". What I want is to get a hexdump-like ACII/unicode  hex codes. Instead of "CODE" in the example i would like to see something like '1F ... 02'

Is there a simple way to achieve it ?

Comment: Your first paragraph doesn't match what you do in the command. In the first paragraph it ses you want something like `hexdump`, `xxd` or the like

Comment: What is wrong with `cat -v` ?

Comment: @muru I have edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: @Rinzwind That actually is neat and useful. Vor most ad-hoc cases i might use it. But what about the weird unicode control characters? printf "\\u007C\\u001C" gives |^\M-oM-;M-?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something *like* sed, with perl:

```
$ printf '\x1F-1f\x09-09\x0A-oa\x0D-0d\x02' | 
    perl -lpe 's/[^[:print:][:space:]]/sprintf "%#x", ord($&)/ge'
0x1f-1f -09
-0d0x2
```

The `e` modifier causes the replacement to be evaluated as an expression.

Comment: Nice. In fact, i was trying to use the **e** modifier for **sed** but it wasn't reliable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ od -tx1z -w16 ~/bin/youtube-dl | head -n 3
0000000 23 21 2f 75 73 72 2f 62 69 6e 2f 65 6e 76 20 70  >#!/usr/bin/env p<
0000020 79 74 68 6f 6e 0a 50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00 08 00  >ython.PK........<
0000040 20 08 21 28 f0 7d e8 fd 33 11 00 00 02 3f 00 00  > .!(.}..3....?..<
```

or with your example:

```
$ printf '\x1F-1f\x09-09\x0A\-oa\x0D-0d\x02' | od -tx1z -w16
0000000 1f 2d 31 66 09 2d 30 39 0a 5c 2d 6f 61 0d 2d 30  >.-1f.-09.\-oa.-0<
0000020 64 02                                            >d.<
0000022
```

Yet another way:

```
$ xxd -g1 -c16  bin/youtube-dl | head -n 3
00000000: 23 21 2f 75 73 72 2f 62 69 6e 2f 65 6e 76 20 70  #!/usr/bin/env p
00000010: 79 74 68 6f 6e 0a 50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00 08 00  ython.PK........
00000020: 20 08 21 28 f0 7d e8 fd 33 11 00 00 02 3f 00 00   .!(.}..3....?..
```